# How can I add UCL and LCL lines to a chart in R

Tags: r, charts, package

I'm using the qicharts2 package to plot a QC graph of random inspections.
I was able to plot an x-bar chart correctly, it even shows the centre line (without a proper tag though) however, I'm unable to add lower and upper control limits, to check which points go beyond it.
The LCL/UCL are defined as constants by QC Dept. so I just assigned those numbers to variables.
This is what i came up with so far:

```
qic (y,
     chart='xbar',
     title="Control Graph",
     ylab="Average",
     xlab="Day",
     subtitle="X-Bar"
     )
lcl <- (10.5-(3*0.18)/5)
ucl <- (10.5+(3*0.18)/5)
```

I tried adding

```
target = lcl, ucl
```

to the end of the instruction (which i'm pretty sure is wrong and gross), but the graph dissapears, however if I add only ucl or lcl, it shows it perfectly.
[image: With ucl]

[image: with lcl]

[image: With both]

I checked the documentation and found nothing in the qicharts2 one. In the qic (not supported anymore) i found:

> standardised:
>   Logical value, if TRUE, creates a standardised control
>   chart, where points are plotted in standard deviation units along with
>   a center line at zero and control limits at 3 and -3. Only relevant
>   for P, U and Xbar charts.

Which is exactly what I'm looking for, however, if I try to use it, I only get the following error:

```
Error in qic(...  :    unused argument (standardised = TRUE)
```

This is just a plus for my homework and not neccesary at all, I just want to know hot to do it, so quick fixes are very welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you best bet is [ggplot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/).

**Example of Usage adding specified LCL + UCL**

Load Package and create dummy data --- using sin function

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(0,360,20))
df$y <- sin(df$x*pi/180)
```

*Plot the graph.*

```
sp <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

**Add UCL + LCL and labels**

```
sp + geom_hline(yintercept=.5, linetype="dashed", color = "red") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=-.5, linetype="dashed", color = "blue") +
  ggtitle("Sin Graph") + ylab("sin(x)") + xlab("Degrees")
```

> geom_hline

This is what allows you to plot the horizontal CL limits.

> geom_text

Add labels to points which have breached, mentioned above want to use the LCL + UCL to visualise this.

```
sp + geom_hline(yintercept=.95, linetype="dashed", color = "red") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=-.95, linetype="dashed", color = "blue") +
  ggtitle("Sin Graph") + ylab("sin(x)") + xlab("Degrees") +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = paste(x," deg")), data = df[abs(df$y)>0.95,],angle=30,size=3)
```

[image]